# How can call collapseGroupsToLevel when changed grouping in wijmo5

Tags: angularjs, report, wijmo

I have implemented default collapse grouping level,but when I changed pagination or changed selection mode of records it will be expand automatically.

So I want to collapse all the node when I changed grouping, pagination and selection mode.

The following is default grouping script

```
$scope.sourceChanged = function(sender, args) {
    sender.collapseGroupsToLevel(4);
}
```

but I want to applied same thing in my below code when I changed grouping

```
$scope.$watch('groupBy', function () {
                    var cv = $scope.assoc_comm_list;
                    cv.groupDescriptions.clear(); // clear current groups
                    if ($scope.groupBy) {
                        var groupNames = $scope.groupBy.split(',');
                        for (var i = 0; i < groupNames.length; i++) {
                            var groupName = groupNames[i];
                            if (groupName == 'date') { // ** group dates by year
                                var groupDesc = new wijmo.collections.PropertyGroupDescription(groupName, function (item, prop) {
                                    return item.date.getFullYear();
                                });
                                cv.groupDescriptions.push(groupDesc);
                            } else if (groupName == 'amount') { // ** group amounts in ranges
                                var groupDesc = new wijmo.collections.PropertyGroupDescription(groupName, function (item, prop) {
                                    return item.amount >= 5000 ? '> 5,000' : item.amount >= 500 ? '500 to 5,000' : '< 500';
                                });
                                cv.groupDescriptions.push(groupDesc);
                            } else { // ** group everything else by value
                                var groupDesc = new wijmo.collections.PropertyGroupDescription(groupName);
                                cv.groupDescriptions.push(groupDesc);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Thanks,

Jignesh

Answer (score 0):

You can access the flexgrid and call collapseGroupsToLevel() method after grouping is applied like this:

```
if ($scope.groupBy) {
for()
{
....
}
flex.collapseGroupsToLevel(4);
}
```

For paging, you can handle the pageChanged event of the CollectionView.